# ffmpeg & ffserverでストリーミング

Tags: ffmpeg

USBカメラの映像を、ffmpegとffserverを使ってWeb配信しようとしていますが、うまく行きません。
以下のffserver.confでffserverを起動すると、同一ネットワークからは`http://localhost:8090/status`で状態を確認できます。

しかし、`http://localhost/test.mjpeg`を開くと、test.mjpegを開くプログラムを選択のダイアログが表示され、Firefoxを選択してもなにも表示されません。
ここで、ffmpegを止めると、ブラウザに映像が表示されます。
ffserverでmjpegのストリミングは出来ないでしょうか？

/etc/ffserver.conf

```conf
HTTPPort 8090
# bind to all IPs aliased or not
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
# max number of simultaneous clients
MaxClients 10
# max bandwidth per-client (kb/s)
MaxBandwidth 10000
# Suppress that if you want to launch ffserver as a daemon.
# NoDaemon

<Feed feed1.ffm>
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 10M
</Feed>

<Stream status.html>
Format status
ACL allow 192.168.12.0 192.168.12.255
</Stream>

<Stream test.mjpeg>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format mjpeg
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize 640x480
VideoBitRate 2048
VideoBufferSize 2048
VideoQMin 5
VideoQMax 51
VideoIntraOnly
NoAudio
Strict -1
</Stream>
```

ffserverの起動

```
ffserver &
```

ffmpegの実行

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 5 -input_format mjpeg \
    -i /dev/video0 http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Comment: 念のため、`ffmpeg(ffserver)`のバージョンやお使いのOS(Linuxでしょうか)に関する情報も追記してもらうとよいかもしれません。

Comment: ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1　ffserverも同じです　
debian 9.4(raspbianですが)